# Не могу запустить программу в PascalABC.Net в Linux MInt

Tags: linux, linux-mint, pascalabc.net

Почему нельзя запустить программу? Установил компилятор как сказано в инструкции, не знаю правильно ли называть это компилятором. Я пользовался этим = это та самая инструкция https://pascalabc.net/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C_PascalABC.NET_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4_Linux
[image: pas]

Answer (score 0):

Пишите на форум разработчикам в Телеграм. В Linux Mint PascalABC.NET запускается без проблем